# How to get a running AR app using Wikitude SDK with Xamarin Component in Visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am going to build a cross-platform mobile app with Augmented Reality experiences using c# programming language. I use Wikitude SDK with Xamarin Component in Visual Studio 2017. I know that Xamarin is integrated now in  Visual Studio 2017 and I am a beginner to these technologies.

I started using the [Wikitude Support for Xamarin](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/xamarin/gettingstartedxamarin.html#introduction-to-the-wikitude-sdk), created android project, and added the Wikitude SDK to the project. But when started with [Example Tutorials](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/xamarin/samples.html#examples-tutorials) and samples on Github, I was unable to proceed and get the running app with AR experience.

Can someone help me in this case to build and run an app with AR experience?

Comment: Something like this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ux4HbnUjNMc)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the SDK to a project as explained here [Augmented Reality Wikitude SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/com.wikitude.xamarin.component) do the following:

- Right click on the Wikitude component and open the containing folder.
- Open the 'samples' folder and continue to open it in visual studio